# Why Typegoose references can always be undefined even when they are required?

Tags: angular, typescript, typegoose

I'm using Typegoose. Here is my Invoice class.

```
export class Invoice extends StatusHistory {
  @prop({ required: true })
  name!: string;
}
```

Here is my Contract class.

```
export class Contract extends StatusHistory {
  @prop({ required: true, ref: () => Invoice })
  invoice!: Ref<Invoice>;
}
```

When I put my mouse over the invoice property, it says:

> (property) `Contract.invoice: Ref<Invoice, string>`

The project is a monorepo and the types are shared between backend and frontend, which is made with Angular. Now, imagine this function inside the contract service:

```
  foo(contract: Contract): any {
    if (contract.invoice) {
      //do some stuff
    }
  }
```

When I put my mouse over the invoice property, it says:

> (property) `Contract.invoice: Ref<Invoice, string | undefined>`

It's ok if I need to check if it's a proper Invoice object or a reference string. But everytime I want to use the invoice property, I need to see if it isn't undefined first even If I know that it's a required property and there is no contract without invoice.

So here's the questions:

- Why the property doesn't have undefined in it's type when I'm in the model file? And why it has when I'm in the frontend file?
- Why Typegoose thinks it can be undefined when it can't since it is required?
- What can I do to make Typegoose see that it can't be undefined so I can stop using a if everytime I want to use this property?

I have searched in typegoose documentation and overall google results but I couldn't find this specific situation.

Comment: you probably have `strictNullChecks` set to `false` in the tsconfig.json of the project where the model file is.

Comment: @TobiasS. It isn't defined but the "scrict" option is set to true. I will try to set strictNullChecks to true, but I believe setting strict to true sets strictNullChecks to true as well

Comment: @TobiasS. actually there was two tsconfig files, one in the backend, that I wasn't aware of and other in the frontend. The first one didn't set strictNullChecks. Thanks! I was thinking this was a Typegoose thing.

Comment: SO's Q&A format is one question at the time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why Typegoose thinks it can be undefined when it can't since it is required?

Decorators can currently not affect the types.

> Why the property doesn't have undefined in it's type when I'm in the model file? And why it has when I'm in the frontend file?
> What can I do to make Typegoose see that it can't be undefined so I can stop using a if everytime I want to use this property?

It is `undefined`, because like the above mentioned thing: decorators cannot affect types. So it would have to be specifically set to be undefined / not be undefined, but also currently (9.x) the `Ref` type is not in a proper state and will be refactored in 10.0, see [#730](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/730).

As a workaround you could use a function like [`assertion`](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/blob/8491757743d7884fc127c17225c4c3737d074fad/src/internal/utils.ts#L611-L623) or use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (which can also be used together with [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)).